# install the latest version from PPA

Tags: ppa, workrave

If I add [this PPA for a newer workrave version by rob caelers](https://launchpad.net/~rob-caelers/+archive/ubuntu/workrave) to my sources.list.d on Ubuntu 14.10 (utopic) and install `workrave`, I only get the version 10.4

How can I install version `1.10.5.0-ppa1~trusty1` ?

Comment: Checked the basics, `apt-get update` and the ppa's online?

Comment: sure, I did apt-get update and installed successfully already, but it results in 10.4 instead of 10.5. I searched more, and there are some deb packages [here](https://launchpad.net/~rob-caelers/+archive/ubuntu/workrave/+build/6534013=) But I cant manage to install them yet (using `dpkg -i`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick & dirty way: go to the ppa with your web browser, browse into http://ppa.launchpad.net/rob-caelers/workrave/ubuntu/pool/main/w/workrave/ and download the specific wanted files, then `dpkg -i` (or `dpkg -i -R [dir with all .deb's]` ) and see if it will work, or needs some other packages?

FYI, got to that link by following your link to the PPA in the Q, then the link in the sources.list entires.

I just tried adding the PPA (ppa:rob-caelers/workrave) to linux mint 17 (based on Ubuntu trusty, uses ubuntu repos) and Synaptic tells me there's 2 versions avaialble, `1.10.1-4 (trusty)` and `1.10.5.0-ppa1~trusty1 (trusty)` and it installs 1.10.5 (so does apt-get). Maybe your apt_preferences, or something else (Synaptic's Lock Version?) is deciding to not update to 1.10.5? Does Synaptic or `apt-cache show workrave` show either/both versions (Synaptic package, Properties -> Versions)? If it says 1.10.5 is available you could force the version, with `apt-get install workrave=1.10.5.0-ppa1~trusty1` or synaptic Package menu -> Force version?

ps. the "Time for a micro-break" mouse-eluding window is a little annoying if not prepared for it ;-)

Comment: cool this worked. Since I have 32bit installed, I downloaded `workrave_1.10.5.0-ppa1~trusty1_i386.deb`,  `workrave-data_1.10.5.0-ppa1~trusty1_all.deb` and `workrave-unity_1.10.5.0-ppa1~trusty1_i386.deb` and installed them with `dpkg -i`. don't download the workrave-gnome package!

Comment: That's good. Not sure why the regular ways wouldn't work, but sometimes my Synaptic refuses to install the newest version of a program too, though it even shows the "upgradable" icon, and I have to "Force Version" from the menu. Tried checking /etc/apt/preferences.d/official-package-repositories.pref & `apt-cache policy` but they _look_ ok, but hard to tell exactly what source a package is from and Synaptic's supposed to "Always prefer the highest version". If I could find the package again maybe I'll ask a Q about it, maybe a bug too?